# How yo create new tab and modify it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new tab and execute script there but this code doesn't work.
I tested it from a page action and the background page console.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"about:blank"}, function(tab){
    console.log(tab.id);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code: 'console.log(2)'});
});
```

Now, the empty tab is created, it also shows the tab.id, but the script is not executed. why?

By the way these are my permission values in the manifest:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not executed, because `<all_urls>` currently [does not support](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084) `about` URLs.

Comment: So there is no way with about URLs?

Comment: @BubuDaba Not at the moment. Another related bug is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76429).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with simple javascript

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'var win = window.open("");win.document.body.style.background = "red"'});
```